# MVC 3 - Assign ViewBag Contents to Javascript string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to pass data from the ViewBag object to javascript on my view.

```
//In the controller

ViewBag.SomeUrl = "http://mydomain.com";

//In the View

<script type="text/javascript">
  var theUrl = " @ViewBag.SomeUrl + ";
</script>
```

The problem I am having is that the following example sets the js var "theUrl" to:

> " + http://mydomain.com + "

Omitting the concatenated quotes causes javascript to bark about the colons obviously. So how can I pass this url as a sting to my javascript var?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why don't you simply output the string like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var theUrl = "@ViewBag.SomeUrl";
</script>
```

The `+` is not run on the server so you do not need it.  The quotes shouldn't cause any issue with getting the value from the ViewBag.

Answer (score 0):

You ARE passing it as a string to your javascript var.  I don't understand what your complaint is.  It's doing exactly what you seem to be wanting it to do.

If your complaint is about the pluses, then remove them from the string.