# Access string stored in a ViewBag on ajax success

Tags: javascript, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm pretty new to ASP.NET MVC, I been searching for a solution for this problem but I couldn't find any proper solution. I found some solutions here on stachoverflow but nothing has worked with me. Here are some links:

[Possible to access MVC ViewBag object from Javascript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10389649/possible-to-access-mvc-viewbag-object-from-javascript-file)

[MVC 3 - Assign ViewBag Contents to Javascript string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919085/mvc-3-assign-viewbag-contents-to-javascript-string)

Here is my ajax call to the server:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', '/Prize/UploadPassport');
        xhr.send(formdata);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)
                if (data.nationality != "") {
                    $('#PassportData tbody').append('<tr><td data-title="@Web.Resources.MyResources.PassportNationality">' + data.nationality + '</td><td data-title="@Web.Resources.MyResources.PassportName">' + data.passportName + '</td><td><a><i id="viewApp_' + data.passportID + '" class="fa fa-search fa-lg" onclick="ViewPassport(' + data.passportID + ');"> <iframe id="img_' + data.passportID + '" class="costumeiframe"></iframe></i></a></td></tr>');
                }
                else {
                    //var errorMsg = data.errorMsg;
                    ShowDataValidationMessage("@ViewBag.FileError"); //here i'm getting an empty string
                }
            }
        }
```

In my server side action I set ViewBag.FileError based on some conditions here it is:

```
public ActionResult UploadPassport(HttpPostedFileBase FileUpload, string PassportCopyNationality)
    {

            if (Condition)
            {
                //Database access
            }

            else
            {
                if (isFileAlreadyExist)
                {
                    ViewBag.FileError = Web.Resources.MyResources.PassportAttachmentValidationForFile;
                }
                else if (file.ContentLength > 3145728 || !isFileTypeLegal)
                {
                    ViewBag.FileError = Web.Resources.MyResources.FileError;
                }

                return Json(new { nationality = "", passportName = "", passportID = "" });
            }


        }
        catch (IOException io)
        {

            return Json("File not uploaded");
        }
    }
```

The problem that I'm getting an empty string

Comment: Your passing json back to the client, not a view so `ViewBag` does not even exist. Just add the value to your `JsonResult`. Not to mention which `@ViewBag.FileError` is razor code which is parsed on the server before you pass the view to the client (in the initial page) so unless you set the value in the initial GET method, it would always return `null`

Comment: @StephenMuecke sorry for that I been on rush !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, `@ViewBag.FileError` (inside your script) is razor code which is parsed on the server before your view is sent to the client, so unless you include `ViewBag.FileError = someValue` in the GET method that generates this view, then it will always equate to `null`.

Secondly, your `UploadPassport()` method is returning a `JsonResult` not a view, so `ViewBag` does not even exist. You can resolve this by adding the value to the `JsonResult`, for example

```
 return Json(new { fileError = someValue, nationality = "", passportName = "", passportID = "" });
```

and then access it in the script

```
ShowDataValidationMessage("data.fileError");
```